# Angular wait for subscribe to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, httpclient, subscribe

I'm trying to implement a test application with Angular. The issue scenario is that I need to do a Get and return a value based on the data gotten from that Get request. See below:

```js
public getNextId(entityName: string): number {
    console.info('Retrieving next ID for  ' + entityName);

    let seqId: SeqId;

    const url = `${this.apiURL}/${entityName}`;

    console.info('SeqID URL: ' + url);

    this.http.get<SeqId>(url)
        .subscribe((data: SeqId) => seqId = data); -> 1

    /*Do something with seqId */ -> 2

    return seqId.nextEntityId;
}
```

The thing is that (2) executes before (1). When (2) is reached seqId variable hasn't been set yet.

How can I do a Get, process the data retrieved and return something, all in the same method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: You have to do the processing inside of the `subscribe` callback.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return an observable from here instead of subscribing

```
  GetData() {return  this.http.get<SeqId>(url)
    .pipe(map(data: SeqId) => seqId = data); 
}
```

And in the controller, subscribe to this method and do the required operation